# How to save using shared preference editor

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-image, saving-data

I need some help. I'm new android developer . I can't save images in shared preferences editor. I would like to saving images my list.

Here's my **Main.java**:

```
public class Main extends ListActivity {

    ArrayList<PersonalInfo> newList = null;
    private Button btnSave = null;

    private EditText txtName = null;
    private EditText txtMobile = null;
    private CustomListAdapter newAdpt = null;
    private int i = 0;
    private ImageView images;
    public static String filename = "MySharedString";
    SharedPreferences someData;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        someData = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
        newList = new ArrayList<PersonalInfo>();

        newAdpt = new CustomListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, newList);
        setListAdapter(this.newAdpt);

        txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        txtMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMobile);
        images = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                newList = new ArrayList<PersonalInfo>();
                PersonalInfo info = new PersonalInfo();
                String dataTxtName = txtName.getText().toString();
                String dataTxtMobile = txtMobile.getText().toString();
                int dataImage = images.getId();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = someData.edit();

                editor.putString("sharedStringName", dataTxtName);
                editor.putString("sharedStringMobile", dataTxtMobile);
                editor.putInt("sharedIntImage", dataImage);

                info.SetName(dataTxtName);
                info.SetMobile(dataTxtMobile);
                info.SetImage(dataImage);
                newList.add(info);


                if (newList != null && newList.size() > 0) {
                    newAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    newAdpt.add(newList.get(0));
                    i++;

                }

                newAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
```

Here's my **PersonalInfo.java**

```
public class PersonalInfo {
    private String name = "";
    private String mobile = "";
    private int image;

    public void SetName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String GetName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void SetMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String GetMobile() {
        return this.mobile;
    }

    public void SetImage(int dataImage) {
        this.image = dataImage;
    }

    public int GetImage() {
        return this.image;
    }
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: what are your images, and what have you tried?

Comment: If you're trying to store an object inside the SharedPreferences, that won't work. You can only store primitive types inside the SharedPreferences.
Instead you could for instance write the path to the images into the SharedPreferences object and then write the images to the SD card as a normal file.
If it's because you're trying to store the PersonalInfo class you need to make it serializable and write it to an objectstream to a file.

Comment: only sending texts in my listrow. images are not sent.

Comment: do u have any tutorial or example. thanx to the advice.

Comment: It's basic Java serialization, so this would work: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm
You need to serialize the objects to for instance the SD card.
Have a look at this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Answer (score 3):

Add `editor.commit();` after you are done with modifying the `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: Also read the doc: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 2):

You have to add editor.commit() every time you make any changes to the SharedPreferences.

Comment: only sending texts in my list row. images are not sending.